# Tensorflow Pipeline for images and numpy files

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am working with tensorflow 2.0.0 and am trying to setup an efficient pipeline for feeding in ~90,000 png images of size (256, 256, 3) and their *labels* which are numpy arrays of size (256,256) for an image segmentation problem. These images and labels won't load fully into memory.

The data are stored in a directory like this:

```
'C:/Users/user/Documents/data/ims/' #png images
'C:/Users/user/Documents/data/masks/' #img labels/masks
```

The file names are the same save the extension so for example "test1.png" and "test1.npy" are an image/label pair.

The data are not split into training, validation, and test subsets yet.

I need to get to a point in which I have both the images and labels split into train, validation, and testing subsets, and also have a means to feed the data into a model for training.

I was following this guide [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/images) but could not figure out how to deal with the numpy files within the get_label function.

I thought I could write a function that splits the data into subsets via file names alone and then on the fly load the batches via the file names provided, but I can't figure out how to do this efficiently.

I'm currently doing this which either doesn't work because the files are too big or too slow because there are some many files to load into memory, either of which isn't a viable solution.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import glob2 as glob
from imageio import imread

base = '/mnt/projects/CNN_Data/clean_data/'

image_path = sorted(glob.glob(base + 'ims/*.png'))
label_path = sorted(glob.glob(base + 'masks/*.npy'))

images = [imread(img).astype(np.float32)/255.0 for img in image_path]
labels = [np.load(path) for path in label_path]
```

Edit to add:

Here was my attempt following the tensorflow example that I linked above. It runs, but I can't get get_label to what I want.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import os

AUTOTUNE = tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE

base = '/mnt/projects/CNN_Data/clean_data/'
list_ds = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(base + 'ims/*')

def get_label(file_path):
    parts = tf.strings.split(file_path, os.path.sep)
    parts[-2] == 'masks'
    fname = tf.strings.split(parts[-1], '.')[0]
    fname = tf.strings.join([fname, '.npy'])
    parts[-1] == fname
    return parts

def decode_img(img):
    img = tf.image.decode_png(img, channels = 3)
    img = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(img, tf.float32)
    return img

def process_path(file_path):
    label = get_label(file_path)
    img = tf.io.read_file(file_path)
    img = decode_img(img)
    return img, label

labeled_ds = list_ds.map(process_path, num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE)
```